# Create URL resource with the scope to node

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-7, wsadmin

I'm creating the URL resorce on WebSphere 7 with the following Jython script:

```
AdminResources.createURL(node, server, urlProvider, 'MyUrl', 'url/MyUrl', '/my/url')
```

The problem is, the scope of new URL Resource is set to node+server. In Admin Console I can create URLs with scope set to cell, node or node+server. How can I set the scope of the new URL Resource from jython script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use createURLAtScope  ,
as example
      AdminResources.createURLAtScope("/Cell:AMYLIN4Cell01/ServerCluster:c1/",
     "myURLProvider", "myURL", "url1/myURL", "myURLSpec", [['category', 'myCategory'], ['description', 'this is my url']])

check for more information http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_7libmail.html#rxml_7libmail__scr27